# How to use a common variable in multiple files in CAPL (How to replace extern)

Tags: capl

I wanted to use a variable in 5 main CAN files. I have one include file common for all 5 CAN files. So I defined and declared the variable in this include file. But when I read the value of the variable from the main files I always get 0. Unfortunately Extern is not available in CAPL. So is there a way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code. How is the variable defined? How do you include the file? ...

Answer (score 1):

If you use CAPL with CANoe you can create a database with the Vector CANdb++ Editor and declare an Environment-Variable in the database.

You Can access this variable in all your CAPL-files like this:

```
putValue(YourEnvironmentVariable,12); // Assigns the value 12 to the variable
Write("%d",getValue(YourEnvironmentVariable); //Prints 12
```

You can also declare an event that is thrown on change of the environment variable.

```
 on envVar YourEnvironmentVariable{//do something...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *System Variables* for global access.

First you want to define a new namespace and a system variable in an include file `global.cin`:

```
/* global.cin */

on Start {
  // define a namespace
  sysDefineNamespace("myNamespace");

  // define an integer system variable with starting, minimum and maximum value
  sysDefineVariableInt("myNamespace", "mySysvar", 0, 0, 99); 
}
```

By including `global.cin` in the `main.can` file you can then access the system variable using the corresponding CAPL functions:

```
/* main.can */

includes
{
  #include "global.cin"
}


on Start {
  // set system variable value
  sysSetVariableInt("myNamespace", "mySysvar", 42));

  // read system variable value
  write("mySysvar: %d", sysGetVariableInt("myNamespace", "mySysvar"));
}
```

For data types other than integer there are corresponding CAPL functions in the naming-style of 
`sysDefineVariable<data-type>()` 
`sysSetVariable<data-type>()` 
 `sysGetVariable<data-type>()` 
You can find additional information about accessing system variables via CAPL in the documentation of CANoe / CANalyzer under `CAPL Functions -> System Variables CAPL Functions`